# Okhttp is quietly retrying requests, is there a way to log the retries?

Tags: android, okhttp

We've been using okhttpClient in our android app, and noticed that OkHttpClient lib is quietly retrying requests, with the config retryOnConnectionFailure boolean in OkHttpClient class.

Is there any way to log the retries? is there a callback or lambda we can use?

I looked into the source code of okhttpClient and did some research, but was not lucky, didn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You log requests via interceptor.

in your *.gradle add

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'
```

and to your OK client:

```
httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
```

Now, there are 2 places to hook an interceptor, `addInterceptor` and `addNetworkInterceptor`. The difference is that regular interceptor shows all requests, including ones served from local cache and network interceptors shows only traffic to a server.

Comment: Thanks. this is great
Is there any easy way to know the retry count of a specific http call, like something we can use in the request or response header??

Comment: @Xiaoqian I don't know about any in particular. You might try writing your own interceptor, maybe there's something there.